# Why can yield be indexed?

Tags: python, python-2.7, indexing, generator, yield

I thought I could make my python (2.7.10) code simpler by directly accessing the index of a value passed to a generator via `send`, and was surprised the code ran. I then discovered an index applied to `yield` doesn't really do anything, nor does it throw an exception:

```
def gen1():
    t = yield[0]
    assert t
    yield False

g = gen1()
next(g)
g.send('char_str')
```

However, if I try to index `yield` thrice or more, I get an exception:

```
def gen1():
    t = yield[0][0][0]
    assert t
    yield False

g = gen1()
next(g)
g.send('char_str')
```

which throws

```
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

This was unusually inconsistent behavior, and I was wondering if there is an intuitive explanation for what indexing yield is actually doing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are not indexing. You are yielding a list; the expression `yield[0]` is really just the same as the following (but without a variable):

```
lst = [0]
yield lst
```

If you look at what `next()` returned you'd have gotten that list:

```
>>> def gen1():
...   t = yield[0]
...   assert t
...   yield False
...
>>> g = gen1()
>>> next(g)
[0]
```

You don't *have* to have a space between `yield` and the `[0]`, that's all.

The exception is caused by you trying to apply the subscription to the contained `0` integer:

```
>>> [0]        # list with one element, the int value 0
[0]
>>> [0][0]     # indexing the first element, so 0
0
>>> [0][0][0]  # trying to index the 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

If you want to index a value sent to the generator, put parentheses around the `yield` expression:

```
t = (yield)[0]
```

Demo:

```
>>> def gen1():
...     t = (yield)[0]
...     print 'Received: {!r}'.format(t)
...     yield False
...
>>> g = gen1()
>>> next(g)
>>> g.send('foo')
Received: 'f'
False
```